# Errors Executing Cordova Commands (Maka-CLI app running on an Android device)

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, meteor

Currently I am trying to run a Maka-CLI web application on my Android device with the command "maka run android-device". However, there is an error that keeps popping up and is as follows:

> => Errors executing Cordova commands:
>
> While running Cordova app for platform Android with options
>   --device:
>
> C:\Users\bnugent\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4\mt-os.windows.
>   x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
>
> throw error;
>   ^
>   ExitWithCode:1

I've scoured the internet for a solution but haven't found anyone with the same issue. I've had success running applications on my Android device with Meteor before, however Maka-CLI has proven to be more of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently "Enable USB Debugging" was disabled on my device. Switching it back on solved the problem. If anyone else gets a vague command line error like that, check Developer Options in your Android device first.